# Why would someone make an XHR to an URL generated by URL.createObjectURL?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to understand the [example code](https://libvorbis-js.surge.sh/) for the [libvorbis.js](https://github.com/Garciat/libvorbis.js) library. The blob with the audio is passed to `URL.createObjectURL`, the URL returned is then used in a XmlHttpRequest with GET that generates another blob which is passed to `URL.createObjectURL` again, and that last URL is used in the download link. Why is that XmlHttpRequest necessary? Can't you just use the URL from the first call to `URL.createObjectURL` in the download link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the author:

> I did that because I encountered a bug in Chrome for Android where it wouldn't want to play the audio from the URL generated from the encoded audio blob directly. The XHR call was simply the workaround that I could come up with at the moment.
>
> More: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227476#c21
>
> It looks like since my comment on Feb 2, the bug has been fixed as of Chrome 50.